# NoSuchFrameException and not able to identify element

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating an web application with selenium webdriver , during which there is a situation,driver has to switch to `iframe` to interact with its element. I am doing all possible steps to switch to `iframe` but still I am getting

> NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id
>   IMW_PROC_MAIN.

Below is the code I tried :

```
driver.switchTo().frame("IMW_PROC_MAIN");
pcw.txt_matterName(driver).sendKeys("TempApplication");
```

I also tried to find total number of iframes on current HTML page and switch by index.
for this ,I am getting an error for text Box as

> NoSuchElementException.

Sharing the screenshot of page source . Due to some restrictions , I am not sharing target HTML text.[image: HTML Page source]

I want to interact with element having `id=matterName`. How I can achieve this.

Comment: I don't mind down votes. but users may want to point out what is wrong / incomplete in this question before down voting it.

Comment: @MKay- Was your issue solved? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`driver.switchTo().frame(1);`

This is using indexing and index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative

```
 WebElement FrameID=driver.findElement(By.id("IMW_PROC_MAIN"));
            driver.switchTo().frame(FrameID);
```

If there are 2 frames nesting with each other then try this:

```
WebElement MAINFrameID=driver.findElement(By.id("GB_FRAME"));
                driver.switchTo().frame(MAINFrameID);
 WebElement FrameID=driver.findElement(By.id("IMW_PROC_MAIN"));
                driver.switchTo().frame(FrameID);
// code for your operation
```

Comment: Yes , it is switching to GB_FRAME but not able to find element by id = IMW_PROC_MAIN.

Answer (score 0):

As you gave higlighted there is another frame called GB_FRAME . First you have to switch to that frame and then switch to IMW_PROC_MAIN frame.
It's frame inside frame. First control should switch to outer frame and then the control will switch to inner one

```
driver.switchTo().frame("GB_FRAME");
driver.switchTo().frame("IMW_PROC_MAIN");
pcw.txt_matterName(driver).sendKeys("TempApplication");
```